# Trouble using Responsivepx locally

Tags: local, responsive-design

I'm trying to use [responsivepx](http://responsivepx.com) to determine breakpoints on a responsive design I am working on locally. I am just dropping the local url into the designated area and trying to open but it doesn't work, and I can't figure out why. Any help would be appreciated. It works fine on external urls fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working locally is difficult because tools such as reponsivepx rely on accessing a publically available URL.  Some options to over come this include;

1. [Create your own iframe page](http://bit.ly/responsivesquiz) and incluse the local url in the source. Using this allows you to set all of the breakpoints you need.
2. [Use Responsive Design Test](http://responsive.victorcoulon.fr/) - provides access to ipad and iphone portrait and landscape modes
3. [Mediaquery Bookmarklet](http://seesparkbox.com/foundry/media_query_bookmarklet) - shows exactly which media queries are currently active and the screen resolution

Comment: @justinavery, may I ask you to have a look at a responsive design relatd question here : http://tinyurl.com/nadfh2u ?